# Colorize UINavigationBar in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I colorized orange my Navigation bar with:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.88 green:0.52 blue:0.27 alpha:1];
```

Everything works ok, every button is as orange as the bar, but when ic cames to a custom right item menu, it shows it blue.
This is a screenshot: http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/5605/schermata20091202a14565.png

and this is the code for the right buttons:

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIToolbar *tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 45)];

NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

UIBarButtonItem *bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addGadget:)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"less.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(setEditing:)];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[buttons release];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
```

How to make everything to be orange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `tintColor` of the `UIToolbar` object to be the same as that of the `UINavigationBar`.

Note that a `UIToolbar` is not the same as a `UINavigationBar`, the background gradient/color is a bit different. Try setting the backgroundColor of the UIToolbar to `+[UIColor clearColor]`

Also, you probably don't even need the container `UIView`, since `UIToolbar` is a subclass of `UIView`, so you can use it as customView just by itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
If it set the backgroundcolor to clear, nothing changes.
If i set the tint to clear, it gives me a black piece,
if i set it to the same orange it lacks of one black pixel on the bottom so it doesn't merge well with the navigationbar

Comment: That's what I said. tintColor should be orange, that's right. You don't want the background to be drawn (since it's different) so I told you to try to set the background color to clear. That doesn't work, so write a `UIToolbar` subclass and override -drawRect: and do nothing, I think that'll be enough.